# VSTS Release Agent 'Failed' to deploy to IIS Site

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am in the process of enabling CI/CD in our NP Environments. I have recently come across an issue where I am deploying to our staging environments which consists of two servers.

The first server deploys no problem, but the second server fails (Or so it says). Upon looking at the IIS Site directory the files do actually get released, but the log would indicated otherwise:

```
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1153713Z Total changes: 231 (229 added, 0 deleted, 2 updated, 0 parameters changed, 53453549 bytes copied)
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1309716Z ##[debug]rc:0
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1309716Z ##[debug]rc:0
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1309716Z ##[debug]success:false
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1309716Z ##[debug]success:false
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1465719Z Error: C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.51\node_modules\webdeployment-common\MSDeploy3.6\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 0
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1465719Z     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\azagent\A1\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.0.51\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\toolrunner.js:569:30)
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1465719Z     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1465719Z     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1465719Z     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1465719Z     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
2019-04-07T21:07:22.1465719Z Retrying to deploy the package.
```

I've tried a couple of things:

1. Making sure the user the release service is running under has the correct permissions to manage that directory.
2. I have reinstalled the Release Agent.

Not sure what else to try or check. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have discovered what the issue was. Funnily enough it appears the issue has stemmed from the environment variable 'COR_PROFILING_ENABLED' being set to enabled '0x01'. It looks like for whatever reason Dynatrace is configured incorrectly and so a Dynatrace specific error is being thrown during the release process.

Since disabling disabling the release successfully completes.